# Unable to display dynamically binded lightning icon in the lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I am facing an issue with the Dynamically binded lightning icon not showing at the required place. I have a simple code attached here. The issue is that if I add the lightning icon through the page level, the icon is showing properly as required, however if I add the lightning icon dynamically through the span using jquery it's not showing up. I have attached screenshot as well as the code. Winter 17 - Salesforce

DemoTestApp.app

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
<c:DemoTest />
</aura:application>
```

DemoTest.cmp

```
<aura:component >
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                       $Resource.jQuery + '/jquery/lightning/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js',
                       $Resource.jQuery + '/jquery/lightning/js/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.min.js')}" 
              afterScriptsLoaded='{!c.doResult}'/>
Component level Info Icon : <span id="infoIcon1"><lightning:icon iconName="utility:info" size="small" /></span>
<br/>
ControllerJs level Info Icon : <span id="infoIcon2"></span>
</aura:component>
```

DemoTestController.js

```
({
doResult : function(component, event, helper) {
    $('#infoIcon2').html('<lightning:icon iconName="utility:info" size="small" />');
}
})
```

Sample output:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Try this : using $A.createComponent()**

**DemoTestApp.app :**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
<c:DemoTest />
</aura:application>
```

**DemoTest.cmp :**

```
<aura:component >
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                       $Resource.jQuery + '/jquery/lightning/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js',
                       $Resource.jQuery + '/jquery/lightning/js/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.min.js')}" 
              afterScriptsLoaded='{!c.doResult}'/>
Component level Info Icon : <span id="infoIcon1"><lightning:icon iconName="utility:info" size="small" /></span>
<br/>
ControllerJs level Info Icon : <span> {!v.body} </span>
</aura:component>
```

**DemoTestController.js :**

```
({
    doResult: function(component, event, helper) {

        $A.createComponent(
            "lightning:icon",
            {
                "iconName": "utility:info",
                "size": "small"
            },
            function(newIcon, status, errorMessage){

                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var body = component.get("v.body");
                    body.push(newIcon);
                    component.set("v.body", body);
                }
                else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                    // Show offline error
                }
                    else if (status === "ERROR") {
                        console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                        // Show error message
                    }
            }
        );
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't add components to the markup with jquery. You need to use `$A.createComponent()` to dynamically create the component and then add it to the page.

The docs for that are [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm).