# Unable to display icon in the lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, spring17

for accessing standard lightning SLDS resource image i am using below tag in visualforce page and i can able to see the image.

`<img src="{!$Asset.SLDS}/assets/icons/utility/chevrondown_60.png" />`

for accessing standard lightning SLDS resource image in the Lightning component i am using below tag but i can't able to see the image.

`<img src="{!$Asset.SLDS+'/assets/icons/utility/chevrondown_60.png'}" />`

if anybody knows the how to access the image in the Lightning component help me (Spring 17).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use icons from SLDS in Lightning Component, you should use the [lightning:icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_icon.htm) Base Component:

```
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:chevrondown" size="small"/>
```

You can then use attributes like size or variant to display the icon in the size and color you want.

Comment: yes but this tag only will work on the component file. can you refer this [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163407/unable-to-display-dynamically-binded-lightning-icon-in-the-lightning-component). in that some body gave solutions but if i add multiple images then i have to use this $A.createComponent() multiple times . it is not efficient solution.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, in your question you are talking about an <img src > tag, this is also in the component file. Where do you want to use it ?

Comment: I want to use in helper js. example $('#devId').html('<lightning:icon iconName="utility:chevrondown" size="small"/>'). but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Like**

```
<img src="{!$Resource.SLDS + '/assets/icons/utility/chevrondown_60.png'}"/>
```

Comment: it will not work. juts $Resource.SLDS is is refer static resource path name SLDS.  but in my case i am not using any Static resource for referring the lightning design system. i am referring the Asset.SLDS.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need to install a helper Lightning Component to render the Lightning Design System icons, try reading this: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/  it may help you.